# Auto generate / detect webserivce methods from the wsdl file in a java based web application

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I need help of awesome tech people here. I'm trying to understand if I can generate a webservice stubs or class automatically using the wsdl file or is it possible to auto detect the methods or services available on the server side. My web application needs to detect these service methods, type of arguments they accept etc.

I know of some tools like wsdl2java or wsimport, but for this, I need to manually run some commands to generate the client stubs. Instead, I'm looking for a solution, where I can upload the wsdl file to my web application and my application can auto generate the java files, integrate it inside the application and start using it. Not sure if this is possible, but this is my requirement.

Please provide your suggestion or guide me to understand the do's or don'ts here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

take a look to this page :

Dynamic Web service invocation from a WSDL : http://www.computing.dcu.ie/~mwang/DI/di.html